# "history" command for android OS

Tags: android, shell, history

I'm am working with MINX android X5 systems.

Being used to linux I am trying to find/use a shell command similar to the linux 'history' command.

Is there any way to install something like this or is there a equivalent with a different name that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: If its unclear perhaps tell me why or how I should clarify if you're taking the time to down vote... I have searched this and other sites as well as the MINX X5 documentation as have my coworkers; to no avail.

Comment: On recent Android versions, the stock shell actually does support history, accessible via the up arrow or the "history" command. It's open source, so you can see where in the git project's evolution it was added - but installing a new version on an existing device is not trivial.